# jqGrid: pass selected IDs as HTML form parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, razor, forms

I have an HTML form (Razor) with jqGrid to select entities (please assume customers, for example).
The customers jqGrid looks like:

```
jQuery("#ajaxGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '@Url.Action("CustomersData")',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "Id" },
    colNames: ['Id', 'Name'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', editable: true, sortable: false, hidden: false },
        { name: 'Name', editable: true, sortable: false, hidden: false }
    ],
    multiselect: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    rowNum: 5,
    width: '850',
    height: '15em'
});
```

So, the grid allows multiple selection.

The question is: how to pass selected customer IDs (as IEnumerable) to the controller on submit (to the appropriate submit action)?

I guess it can be done by setting all selected IDs as form parameter. I don't know how to copy the data from the array:

```
var ids = jQuery("#ajaxGrid").getGridParam('selarrrow');
```

to HTML form hidden value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct you can for example create string with comma-separated ids of selected rows with respect of `ids.join(',')`. Then you can use the `jQuery.val(newValue)` to set the new halue to the hidden field: `$("#hiddenFieldId").val(ids.join(','));`.

Comment: Ok, I see the point. When should I do it? Before posting the form?

Comment: @Serge: Of course you should set hidden field before submitting or posting. The best place to do this depend on the organisation of your program. The way which will definitively work is setting of hidden field inside of `onSelectRow` event handler.

Comment: This is the best answer to this question that i've seen. Thank you so much. This is very elegant and clean.

Comment: @DanTheLion: Thank you! I'm glad that the answer could help you too.