# pass selected jqGrid rows to button with action

Tags: grails, jqgrid, controller

I have a grails view with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* when the page has finished loading.. execute the follow */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#customer_list").jqGrid({
          url:'jq_customer_list',
          datatype: "json",
          colNames:['customer','location','id'],
          colModel:[
            {name:'customer'},
            {name:'location',stype:'select', searchoptions:{value:':All;USA:USA;Canada:Canada;Carribean:Carribean;USPacific:USPacific;'}},
            {name:'id', hidden:true}
          ],
          rowNum:2,
          rowList:[1,2,3,4],
          pager: jQuery('#customer_list_pager'),
          viewrecords: true,
          gridview: true,
          multiselect: true
        });
        $("#customer_list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{autosearch:true});
    });
    </script>
<g:link controller="MyController" action="downloadFile">Download</g:link><br>
  </div>
<br/><br/>
```

Now I would like to pass into this action the data from the selected rows.  However, I can't find this anywhere.

My method on my controller currently is blank.  I would just like to print to the console all the IDs of the selected values.

Any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: Create a hidden input to store the value. Whatever the name of the input is, is what you reference it by in the controller. `params.name`

Comment: this related post should get you going [jqGrid: pass selected IDs as HTML form parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836192/jqgrid-pass-selected-ids-as-html-form-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e){
    console.log('Id of Selected Row: ' + $(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'id'));
}
```

Comment: How would I pass this into g:link action?

Comment: Not familiar with grails, what are you looking to do exactly? All this does is tell the jqGrid that when a row is selected to extract some data from the selected row, and in this display it to the console.   There should be no reason why you couldn't pass this to something else.

Comment: I am trying to pass this into a post action to download a file with all the data on it

Comment: Sounds straightforward then...you can use the above concept to grab whatever information from the cells of the selected row to pass along in your post action to download the associated PDF.

Comment: So I would grab the ids and how would I post them to the action in my controller?  Sorry, still new to grails

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with grails, you would need to look into an Ajax post call in your javascript via jQuery.  Basically sounds like you are on the hunt now for how to do an Ajax post via jQuery.